# My PHPMailer script works on my laptop but not on the hosting server

Tags: gmail, phpmailer

Problem sending email with PHPMailer.

I am aware that there are quite a few questions about this but after reading lots of them and after three days of fruitless attempts I am really desperate. So, I am trying to send an email via PHPMailer:

```
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->PluginDir = './';
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'myname@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';

$mail->From = "myname@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "MyName";
$mail->addAddress("myname@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject = "Success";
$mail->Body = "Success";

if(!$mail->Send()) echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
else echo "Message has been sent";
```

When I test this code on my laptop it works perfectly. The local php and PHPMailer versions are 5.3.5 and 5.2.4 respectively. The problem arises when I try to upload this script on my website. The php version on the hosting server is 5.3.3. The returned error is "The following From address failed: myname@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected."
I have experienced this error previously while I was testing the code on my machine. The problem was that the ssl module(php_openssl.dll) wasn't added in php.ini. I added it and everything started to work fine. So naturally, when I saw this error I assumed that openssl is not loaded on the hosting server. But it turned out that this is not the case - extension_loaded("openssl") returns true. Moreover, "openssl" is contained in the array of loaded modules returned from get_loaded_extensions().
Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: try the following:
**1.** $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; to get more info
**2.** use tls in the place of ssl
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
**3.** use port 587:  $mail->Port = 587;

Comment: You can also check this full example on the [GitHub](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/test_smtp_gmail_advanced.php)

Comment: It turned out that my provider was blocking the the gmail server. All these efforts for such a stupid problem... Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: no problem.. don't forget the SMTP debug option in the future... it;s so useful!  Run it on your laptop, and see for yourself what sort of output it gives!  :)